# What regular expression matches this pattern: 22-NOV-09

Tags: regex

I have tried:

```
/^([0-3][0-9])-(A-Za-z)-([0-1][0-9])?$/
```

and am not having success. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you folks!

Comment: Do you need the regex to verify if a date is a valid date? In that case I would refrain from such regexes, they also match 39-OTZ-03 which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you - the thing is that I'm not validating user input, I'm making sure I don't have a column offset problem when parsing CSV imports.  It is the only column in such a format and fastcodejava's answer is working like a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^([0-3][0-9])-([A-Z]{3})-([0-1][0-9])$/
```

EDIT : 
`/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-([A-Z]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-9])$/`

Answer (score 3):

To be overly pedantic, this regular expression matches it: `22-NOV-09`.

If what you want instead is to verify whether a given string is a validate date in a specific format, then I'd recommend using something like [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).  For example:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct tm tm;
   char *p;

   p = strptime(argv[1], "%d-%b-%y", &tm);
   if (p && *p == '\0')  {
      printf("Matches\n");
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      printf("Didn't match\n");
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Python has [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#datetime.datetime.strptime), and Perl has [`POSIX::strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POSIX-strptime/).  I'm sure most other languages have access to this function, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^([0-3][0-9])-([A-Za-z]+)-([0-1][0-9])$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Character classes are to be represented with square brackets.

```
/^([0-3][0-9])-([A-Za-z]+)-([0-1][0-9])?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the **?**.  And you can drop the parens unless you're pulling sub-string matches:

```
/^([0-3][0-9])-([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])-([0-1][0-9])$/
```

or

```
/^[0-3][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-1][0-9]$/
```